# Is there a finite set of distinct naturals whose reciprocals sum to 1, and no element in the set is one less than a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, egyptian-fractions

I'll try to state this formally, forgive me if I botch the notation. Let

$$R=\{n : n+1 \in\mathbb{P}\}.$$ (Where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes)

Then the question is,

$$\exists S \subset (\mathbb{N} \setminus R)\text{ for }s\text{ of finite length, such that }\sum_{s\in S}{\frac{1}{s}}=1 ?$$

It is not hard to find finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose reciprocals sum to $1$, such as the trivial $\{1\}$, or $\{2,3,6\}$. I [suspect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470540/are-there-infinitely-many-finite-sets-s-of-primes-where-sum-p-in-s-1-p-i) that there are infinitely many finite subsets of $R$ with this property, such as $\{2,4,6,12\}$ or $\{2,4,6,18,36\}$.

However, I couldn't find any valid $S$ with a quick search through small numbers, and I'm wondering if it's known whether such a set exists.

Comment: Context for this question please?

Comment: No context other than mathematical curiosity, after looking again at the post I linked to. It seems potentially "interesting" if indeed no such set exists.

Comment: That is mathematical curiosity is certainly fair, it is an interesting question. However, anyone spending energy on trying to come up with a solution deserves IMO to know e.g., whether or not this is a homework exercise or a contest question with a known solution.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Then to be clear, no, this was just my own supposition. It is not a contest question to the best of my knowledge, and I left homework behind many years ago.

Comment: fair enough... +1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can use the formula
$$
\frac1n = \frac1{n+1} + \frac1{n(n+1)}
$$
to obtain such a sum. Start with
$$
1 = \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \frac18 
$$
Now, for $n=8$ we can rewrite the last term as
$$
\frac18=\frac19+\frac{1}{72}
$$
Since $72+1$ is a prime, we have to iterate this, i.e.,
$$
\frac18=\frac19+\frac{1}{73}+\frac{1}{5256}.
$$
Similarly
$$
\frac12=\frac13+\frac17+\frac{1}{43}+\frac{1}{1806}
$$
and
$$
\frac14=\frac15+\frac{1}{20}.
$$
Together we obtain
$$
1=\left(\frac13+\frac17+\frac{1}{43}+\frac{1}{1806}\right)+\left(\frac15+\frac{1}{20}\right)+\frac18+\left(\frac19+\frac{1}{73}+\frac{1}{5256}\right).
$$
All denominators plus one are not prime numbers.

Answer (score 13):

Your denominators can include any odd number greater than $1$.

Find an odd semiperfect number $n$ (some subset of its proper factors add to $n$). $945$ is the smallest such number. Write $945$ as a sum of (some) of its proper factors. Then divide by $945$.

$945=315+189+135+105+63+45+35+27+15+9+7$.

So $1=\frac{315+189+135+105+63+45+35+27+15+9+7}{945}$.

That is $$1=\frac13+\frac15+\frac17+\frac19+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{35}+\frac{1}{63}+\frac{1}{105}+\frac{1}{135}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's the greedy solution, obtained by repeatedly choosing the largest possible fraction whose denominator isn't one less than a prime.

$$ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{13} + \frac{1}{93} + \frac{1}{44155} + \frac{1}{8968410360}$$

And note that $8968410361$ is $241 * 347 * 107243$, from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=8968410361).

You can find new terms by editing the following very crude lisp program, which computes the smallest possible denominator for the next term (without checking the primality condition).

```
(ceiling (/ 1 (- (1- (+ 1/3 1/5 1/7 1/8 1/9)))))
```